# Sections are Overlapping In HTML

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to get my sections to stop overlapping in HTML/CSS. I've tried using margin and padding but they're not working.

HTML and CSS:

```css
  #projects {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  #education {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="projects">
    <!--there's a lot of irrelevant code in the middle here-->
  </section>

  <section id="education">
    <!--there's a lot of irrelevant code in the middle here-->
  </section>
</body>
```

Result when I shrink the page:
[image: error]

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please send your HTML and CSS

Comment: Add some relevant code - Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something ? Please do your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a minimal example of your work. Read here how to ask a [GOOD question]

Comment: Definitely need your HTML and CSS. A screen shot showing the issue would also help.

Answer (score 0):

probably your content in the `projects` section is longer than the fixed `height: 100vh` and you're not handling the overlapping content.

try changing you `height` to `min-height` or handling content with css property `overflow/overflow-y`