# Section Tags keep overlapping when I shrink the page

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to get my sections to stop overlapping in HTML/CSS. I've tried using margin and padding and float in CCS but they're not working.

```css
 #projects{
            display: block;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
            padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            }
    
            #education{
                display: block;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
                padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            }
```

```html
    <body>
         <section id="projects"> 
            <!--there's a lot of irrelevant code in the middle here-->
        </section>
        
           <section id="education"> 
            <!--there's a lot of irrelevant code in the middle here-->
        </section>
    </body>
```

Result when I shrink the page: [image: error]

Comment: Please don’t repost the same questions. You already [asked this exact question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748165/sections-are-overlapping-in-html). It will be in the queue for review to be reopened since you edited it.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate your issue without adding too much of my own code. Could you share more content of your files?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was just permanently deleted so I updated here.